# windows 7 doesn't allow my third monitor to work

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have an "ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650" Graphics card, with 1 VGA and 1 HDMI port, + main monitor on my laptop and 2 external monitors. I'm trying to connect my third monitor but whenever I try to "extend desktop to this display" the other external monitors goes off.

[image: http://palprof.com/monitors.png]

I just tried it on Ubuntu and the 3 worked perfectly. On Windows 7 they are not, also tried Catalyst it does detect 3 monitors but when I go to Create Eyefinity group, it only shows 2.

I tried having Windows 7 auto update graphics card drivers, still same problem.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Your hardware does not allow connecting hdmi and vga at the same time.
Most hardware even modern ones do not allow this.
There is a usb to vga cable though that will allow you to circumvent this and have your third monitor appear simultaneously.

Comment: Come on Ahmad, why is it working on Linux with no problems if it's a hardware issue

Comment: Drivers perhaps, did your laptop originally come with Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the Graphics driver directly from the Manufacturer. Don't install it using Windows Update or by letting the Driver Installer search online.

Comment: Driver had Problem in Windows . in Linux you not see but it's installed before on the Kernel and your ubuntu . but windows is Different